# Sink top: spray gun lacquer or metal enamel?

Tags: paint, metal, steel, spraypainting

I am thinking in mounting a washbasin into a 3mm steel plate. The plate will be painted in a Klein Blue.

Considering that it will get wet and that there won't be too much ventilation in the room... Which method do you think it would be best for painting it?

I am considering to do it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a two part epoxy paint, it's kind of sticky but if you apply it right you can use a roller.

Comment: You can apply it "right" with sprayer, brush or roller - at least we did...

Comment: Buy a cheap foam roller and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to primer it with red oxide and for final painting, use odorless enamel. should be enough for your

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you finish your answer? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.